# modify a new col value based on other col values in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am struggling to achieve the following:

```
df=
  c1 c2 c3 c4
1  1  4  2  5
2  1  2  3  4
3  3  4  5  5
4  1  2  5  5
5  2  3  5  5
```

for each observation(i.e. row) if any of the col i.e. col1, col2, col3, col4 has both 1&4 values or only 1 or only 4; then set c5 (a new column) to 14, 1, 4 respectively for the cases else set it to -1. So c5 value I want to achieve is

```
c5
14
14
4
1
-1
```

Wanted to achieve it using dplyr package and mutate functionality like below but its giving error.

```
df = df %>% mutate (c5= ifelse(c(df$c1,df$c2,df$c3,df$c4 %in% c(1,4), 14, 
                        ifelse(c(df$c1,df$c2,df$c3,df$c4 %in% c(1),1, 
                        ifelse(c(df$c1,df$c2,df$c3,df$c4 %in% c(4),-1))))
```

What is the right and efficient way to achieve this please ?

Answer (score 2):

Make two vectorised comparisons, then look at their interaction:

```
one <- rowSums(df == 1) > 0
four <- rowSums(df == 4) > 0
c(-1,1,4,14)[interaction(one,four)]
#[1] 14 14  4  1 -1
```

Or all in one line if you want:

```
c(-1,1,4,14)[interaction( rowSums(df==1) > 0, rowSums(df==4) > 0 )]
#[1] 14 14  4  1 -1
```

Comment: This looks fabulous, however what if there are other columns as well in the data frame which I don't want to look at and disturb. So in that case, how do I specify only the relevant columns instead of full data frame within rowSums ?

Comment: @mbansal - just specify them - `vars <- c("x","y")` and then replace `df` with `df[vars]`

Answer (score 1):

This is using base R. You can use the idea with the dplyr package

```
   dat$c5=apply(dat,1,function(x){y=x%in%c(1,4);
                     ifelse(any(y),as.numeric(paste0(sort(unique(x[y])),collapse = "")),-1)})
      dat
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
 1  1  4  2  5 14
 2  1  2  3  4 14
 3  3  4  5  5  4
 4  1  2  5  5  1
 5  2  3  5  5 -1
```

Comment: Thanks, works well but not sure if I follow well, when you have time care to walk through please ? specifically the use of collapse.

Comment: There is a problem with the solution, I wasn't clear enough. The value of c5 is dependent currently on the sequence of 1 and 4, if I swap their sequence it becomes 41. Irrespective of the order, I want col5 value as 14

Comment: First you look whether 1 or 4 or both are present in the rows. This is by the use of `%in%` function. Then if present take the ones that are present and put them together using the `paste` function. Or if not, output -1.

Comment: I have fixed your problem. I guess you needed you alse needed a scenario where even if you had 3 4's and a 1 you still needed 14.. It is all sorted out

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr`. `rowSums(. == 1)` and `rowSums(. == 4)` are to how many elements are `1` or `4`, respectively. `case_when` is to assign the replacement value. The idea is similar to your original multiple `ifelse` statement, but `case_when` can provide a more clear concise way to specify conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(c5 = case_when(
    rowSums(. == 1) > 0 & rowSums(. == 4) > 0     ~ 14,
    rowSums(. == 1) > 0 & rowSums(. == 4) == 0    ~  1,
    rowSums(. == 1) == 0 & rowSums(. == 4) > 0    ~  4,
    TRUE                                          ~ -1
  ))
df2
#   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
# 1  1  4  2  5 14
# 2  1  2  3  4 14
# 3  3  4  5  5  4
# 4  1  2  5  5  1
# 5  2  3  5  5 -1
```

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = "  c1 c2 c3 c4
1  1  4  2  5
2  1  2  3  4
3  3  4  5  5
4  1  2  5  5
5  2  3  5  5",
                 header = TRUE)
```